# try convert vert to circle using hops tool

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

[image]

hello,
i try convert vert from cylinder to circle using hops tool but i got some error can anybody help me, thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but your version of HOps is way out of date. Download v0.9.86.26 from whatever merchant you bought it from and try again.

Comment: u got a point :) thx